# Calling self.send iteratively on a hash argument to initialize()

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand the following Ruby code.

It looks like `attrs` is a hash that gets passed as an argument with a default value of an empty hash.

Then `attrs.each` iterates over the key, value pairs in the hash (`|k,v|`).

What effect is achieved by calling `self.send` on the elements of the key value pair during this iteration?

```
def initialize(attrs = {}, *args)
  super(*args)
  attrs.each do |k,v|
    self.send "#{k}=", v
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 I love using this code for flexible object creation/initialisation. See my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778638/idiomatic-object-creation-in-ruby/5272354#5272354

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`send` calls the method in the first parameter, and passes the rest of the parameters as arguments.

In this case I assume what's in `attrs` is a list of attributes. Let's say it's something like this:

```
{ :name => "John Smith" }
```

So then in the loop, it does this:

```
self.send "name=", "John Smith"
```

which is equivalent to

```
self.name = "John Smith"
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks. So, that means in your example name becomes a class method, right - because of [self.]name?

Comment: First of all, that example isn't creating a method at all -- it's calling the method `name=`, which must already exist. Secondly, self inside an instance method (such as initialize) refers to the instance. So this is calling an instance method.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that the `name=` methods are automatically created by the `attr_accessor :name` helper.

Comment: The methods being called by #send are _NOT_ class methods; they are instance methods. "self." is used to define or call class methods from class scope, or to define or call instance methods from instance scope. #initialize is an instance method, so its scope is instance scope.