# Idiomatic object creation in ruby

Tags: ruby

In ruby, I often find myself writing the following:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(bar, baz)
    @bar = bar
    @baz = baz
  end

  << more stuff >>

end
```

or even

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :baz

  def initialize(bar, baz)
    @bar = bar
    @baz = baz
  end

  << more stuff >>

end
```

I'm always keen to minimise boilerplate as much as possible - so is there a more idiomatic way of creating objects in ruby?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763016/how-to-cleanly-initialize-attributes-in-ruby-with-new

Answer (score 12):

One option is that you can inherit your class definition from Struct:

```
class Foo < Struct.new(:bar, :baz)
  # << more stuff >>
end

f = Foo.new("bar value","baz value")
f.bar #=> "bar value"
f.baz #=> "baz value"
```

Comment: Instead of subclassing you can also do  `Foo = Struct.new(:bar, :baz) do ... end`

Comment: Can you provide an example, sepp2k?

Comment: Interesting... but what if you want Foo to subclass something else?

Comment: It's worth noting that a Struct isn't exactly same as just a bunch of macros that do all the boilerplate class stuff for you.

Answer (score 10):

I asked [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844457), and suggested my own answer there, expecting for a better one, but a satisfactory one did not appear. I will post my own one.

Define a class method like the following along the spirit of `attr_accessor`, `attr_reader`, `attr_writer` methods.

```
class Class
    def attr_constructor *vars
        define_method("initialize") do |*vals|
            vars.zip(vals){|var, val| instance_variable_set("@#{var}", val)}
        end
    end
end
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
class Foo
    attr_constructor :foo, :bar, :buz
end

p Foo.new('a', 'b', 'c')      # => #<Foo:0x93f3e4c @foo="a", @bar="b", @buz="c">
p Foo.new('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') # => #<Foo:0x93f3e4d @foo="a", @bar="b", @buz="c">
p Foo.new('a', 'b')           # => #<Foo:0x93f3e4e @foo="a", @bar="b", @buz=nil>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Struct

`Struct` object's are classes which do almost what you want. The only difference is, the initialize method has nil as default value for all it's arguments. You use it like this

```
A= Struct.new(:a, :b, :c)
```

or

```
class A < Struc.new(:a, :b, :c)
end
```

`Struct` has one big drawback. You can not inherit from another class.

## Write your own attribute specifier

You could write your own method to specify attributes

```
def attributes(*attr)
  self.class_eval do
    attr.each { |a| attr_accessor a }
    class_variable_set(:@@attributes, attr)

      def self.get_attributes
        class_variable_get(:@@attributes)
      end

      def initialize(*vars)
        attr= self.class.get_attributes
        raise ArgumentError unless vars.size == attr.size
        attr.each_with_index { |a, ind| send(:"#{a}=", vars[ind]) }
        super()
      end
  end
end

class A
end

class B < A
  attributes :a, :b, :c
end
```

Now your class can inherit from other classes. The only drawback here is, you can not get the number of arguments for initialize. This is the same for `Struct`.

```
B.method(:initialize).arity # => -1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus), I don't think it's the idiomatic way to do so but it does all the boiler plate for you.

```
require 'Virtus'

class Foo
  include 'Virtus'

  attribute :bar, Object 
  attribute :baz, Object

end
```

Then you can do things like

```
foo = Foo.new(:bar => "bar") 
foo.bar # => bar
```

If you don't like to pass an hash to the initializer then add :

```
def initialize(bar, baz)
  super(:bar => bar, :baz => baz)
end
```

If you don't think it's DRY enough, you can also do

```
def initialize(*args)
  super(self.class.attributes.map(&:name).zip(args)])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes do

```
@bar, @baz = bar, baz
```

Still boilerplate, but it only takes up one line.

I guess you could also do

```
["bar", "baz"].each do |variable_name|
  instance_variable_set(:"@#{variable_name}", eval(variable_name))
end
```

(I'm sure there's a less dangerous way to do that, mind you)

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5825 is a proposal to make the boilerplate less verbose.

Answer (score -1):

You could use an object as param.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :param

  def initialize(p)
    @param = p
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.param.bar = 1
f.param.bax = 2
```

This does not save much lines in this case but it will if your class has to handle a large number of param. You could also implement a set_param and get_param method if you want to keep your @param var private.