# Mass assignment on construction from within ruby

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, syntax, constructor, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Idiomatic object creation in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778638/idiomatic-object-creation-in-ruby)

Sometimes it's useful to assign numerous of a constructed arguments to instance variables on construction. Other than the obvious method:

```
def initialize(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  @arg1, @arg2, @arg3 = arg1, arg2, arg3
end
```

Is there a more concise idiom for achieving the same result? Something like that found in scala for instance:

```
class FancyGreeter(greeting: String) {
  def greet() = println(greeting)
}
```

Where in this case the object FancyGreeter has a default constructor that provides assignment for it's passed arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778638/idiomatic-object-creation-in-ruby

Comment: It would certainly seem to be a duplicate now you have pointed it out (I had searched but my search terms were miles off that questions title.) I think the titles are distinct enough to allow different people searching for an answer to the same question to happily locate one or the other and thus i am a little loth to delete this question... What do people think?

Comment: Duplicate questions are generally closed (no new answers can be added) rather than deleted (sent to /dev/null).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby 1.8, block arguments and method arguments have different semantics: method arguments have *binding semantics*, block arguments have *assignment semantics*.

What that means is that when you call a method, the method arguments get *bound* to the values that you pass in. When you call a block, the values get *assigned* to the arguments.

So, you can create some pretty crazy looking blocks that way, that seemingly don't do anything:

```
lambda {|@a|}.call(42)
```

The block body is empty, but because of the argument assignment semantics, the instance variable `@a` will be assigned the value `42`. It works even crazier:

```
lambda {|foo.bar|}.call(42)
```

Yes, `attr_writer` methods work too. Or what about

```
foo = {}
lambda {|foo[:bar]|}.call(42)
p foo # => {:bar => 42}
```

Yup, those too.

And since you can define methods using blocks, you can do this:

```
class FancyGreeter
  define_method(:initialize) {|@greeting|}
  def greet; puts @greeting end
end
```

or even

```
class FancyGreeter
  attr_accessor :greeting
  define_method(:initialize) {|self.greeting|}
  def greet; puts greeting end
end
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this for two reasons:

- Not many Rubyists know this, be kind to the people who have to maintain the code after you.
- In Ruby 1.9 and onwards, block argument semantics are gone, blocks also use method argument semantics, therefore this does no longer work.

Comment: Fantastic intro to block assignment semantics. Seriously interesting :) I am going to have to go and read yet more about this stuff now!!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could do....

```
def initialize *e
  @a, @b, @c = e
end
```

Comment: I would of course prefer maintaining argument length knowledge but yes this is certainly more concise... Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "better" but there are varying levels of 'clever':

```
def initialize args={}
  args.each do |key, value|
    instance_variable_set "@#{key}", value
  end
end
```

But "clever" is usually dangerous when you program :-)

---

Edit: Given the edited question, I'll add this:

```
Class PickMe
  def initialize say="what?"
    @say = say
  end
end
```

Just because I don't know if you're aware of default options. Otherwise, think of the value of self-documenting code. A cleanly-written 'initialize' method is priceless.

Comment: +1 for cleverness, -1 for cleverness. ;)

Comment: changed 'better' for 'more concise' damn my generalities!

Answer (score 0):

It was either Andy Hunt or Dave Thomas who proposed that Ruby should be able to handle this syntax for initializing member variables from constructor arguments:

```
  def initialize(@a, @b, @c)
     ...
  end
```

Matz did not accept their proposal; I don't remember why.

Comment: Shame, i would say exactly what i desire. I am going to go and hunt down said proposal and try and find out Matz's rejection reasons.

Comment: Which is different to not remembering _why's opinion. Sorry, bad pun.