# How to generate initializer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, initializer

It's time to make it shorter:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c, :d, :e

  def initialize(a, b, c, d, e)
    @a = a
    @b = b
    @c = c
    @d = d
    @e = e
  end
end
```

We have 'attr_accessor' to generate getters and setters.

Do we have anything to generate initializers by attributes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Idiomatic object creation in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778638/idiomatic-object-creation-in-ruby)

Comment: `def initialize(*args)` ... `@a,@b,@c,@d,@e = args`

Answer (score 15):

Easiest:

```
Foo = Struct.new( :a, :b, :c )
```

Generates both accessors and initializer. You can further customize your class with:

```
Foo = Struct.new( … ) do
  def some_method
    …
  end
end
```

Comment: This is neat. I'd never thought about using a Struct for that purpose before. Of course, it comes with limitations, like the inability to descend from some other class too.

Comment: You can also do `class Foo < Struct.new(:a, :b, :c)`.

Comment: @d11wtq You can inherit from or to a Struct.

Comment: @Andrew Nice, I had never thought to do that before.

Answer (score 2):

We can create something like `def_initializer` like this:

```
# Create a new Module-level method "def_initializer"
class Module
  def def_initializer(*args)
    self.class_eval <<END
      def initialize(#{args.join(", ")})
        #{args.map { |arg| "@#{arg} = #{arg}" }.join("\n")}
      end
END
  end
end

# Use it like this
class Foo
  attr_accessor   :a, :b, :c, :d
  def_initializer :a, :b, :c, :d

  def test
    puts a, b, c, d
  end
end

# Testing
Foo.new(1, 2, 3, 4).test

# Outputs:
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

Comment: +1 for using the string form of `eval` to require the proper arity. You should probably place this method on `Module` or the singleton class of `Class`, as there's not a lot of sense in using this on object instances other than classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a gem like [constructor](http://rubygems.org/gems/constructor). From the description:

> Declarative means to define object properties by passing a hash to the constructor, which will set the corresponding ivars.

It is easily used:

```
Class Foo
  constructor :a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :accessors => true
end

foo = Foo.new(:a => 'hello world', :b => 'b',:c => 'c', :d => 'd', :e => 'e')
puts foo.a # 'hello world'
```

If you don't want the ivars generated with accessors, you can leave off the :accessors => true

Hope this helps
/Salernost

Answer (score 1):

```
class Module
  def initialize_with( *names )
    define_method :initialize do |*args|
      names.zip(args).each do |name,val|
        instance_variable_set :"@#{name}", val
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is pretty nice, except it will skip the normal `initialize` argument checking: `initialize_with :a, :b` + `Foo.new(1,2,3,4,5)` will produce no error.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Foo
  class InvalidAttrbute < StandardError; end

  ACCESSORS = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]
  ACCESSORS.each{ |atr| attr_accessor atr }

  def initialize(args)
    args.each do |atr, val|
      raise InvalidAttrbute, "Invalid attribute for Foo class: #{atr}" unless ACCESSORS.include? atr
      instance_variable_set("@#{atr}", val)
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo.new(a: 1)
puts foo.a
#=> 1

foo = Foo.new(invalid: 1)
#=> Exception
```

Comment: I think the opening sentence was something along the lines of "It's time to make it shorter" ;)

Comment: Yeap. But Struct do pretty the same underneath :)